# In visual basic is there a way to make the character move without any stops in-between making it move in another direction?

Tags: vb.net

I have this game in vb, I am using this code;

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown 
    Select Case e.KeyCode 
       Case Keys.Left 
       Player.Left -= 10 
       Case Keys.Right 
       Player.Left += 10 
       Case Keys.Down 
       Player.Top += 10 
       Case Keys.Up 
       Player.Top -= 10 
       Case Keys.Escape 
       End 
    End Select 
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that when I make the character move in a different direction, the character stops for a sec then moves in that direction so I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this, by the way my teacher isn't letting me use Direct X or anything else just Visual basic 
Thanks to anyone who can help me

Comment: That code doesn't seem to be the issue, the problem is likely in the code that draws the display and updates it

Comment: you could just program the movement horizontal and movement vertical and change the player position on change of a timer. When a key is pressed, you could then change the movement properties

Comment: this code will work only when form has `focus`

Comment: You might want to use acceleration for movement instead of forcing values - that way you would lose some of the 'jerkiness' that this movement style would create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most basically, i would see you could use this

Requires: A timer which is already started (Timer1), and the Keydown event

This would start moving the puppet as soon as you press a directional key, and would change on each timer tick (so relatively fluid)

```
Dim movement As New Point(0, 0)

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Left
            movement.X = -10
            movement.Y = 0
        Case Keys.Right
            movement.X = 10
            movement.Y = 0
        Case Keys.Up
            movement.X = 0
            movement.Y = -10
        Case Keys.Down
            movement.X = 0
            movement.Y = 10
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lblPlayer.Left += movement.X
    lblPlayer.Top += movement.Y
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise but the problem here is that the character keeps moving and don't want that to happen, i want it to stop when i let got of the keys

Comment: Then, add a KeyUp event to set the movement.X and movement.Y to 0?